# Viewing images from pickle file in python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, pickle

I am a newbie in Machine Learning.I have a **dataset of images** present in **.p format(pickle)**.

How to view the images present inside the file ? I seached the internet but I didn't any appropriate answers.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
objects = []
with (open("full_CNN_train.p", "rb")) as openfile:
    while True:
        try:
            objects.append(pickle.load(openfile))
        except EOFError:
            break
        
print(objects)
```

My output when I tried pickle.load()

[image]

Comment: What did you get when you tried `pickle.load()` on the file?

Comment: Hi I have added the output screenshot above. I got some matrix array values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load the pickle file, and use the "imshow" method to visualize.

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pkl = open('pickled_image.pickle', 'rb')
im = pickle.load(pkl)

plt.imshow(im)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I applied that and I got TypeError: Invalid shape (12764, 80, 160, 3) for image data. So I added  plt.imshow(im[0])  to it. Now it is working fine but I am able to view only 1 image but I have multiple images in it. Is there anything should I add to it ?

Comment: Okay, that means in your image file you have 12764 images, 80 pixels by 160 pixels by 3 channels.... you could do plt.imshow(im[i]) in a for loop where you iterate i to the length of your image file... but this does not sound like what you want to do as it will show ALL of your images. If you wanted to just take a look at a few images you could do plt.imshow(im[1]), plt.imshow(im[3]) etc. or again iterate i from 0 to a certain number.. but it all depends on how many images you want to look at!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably just a standard image matrix, just try using matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = ... # pickle load or whatever

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. Can you show how to do that in code? I will add the code I used above. Sorry and thank you !

Comment: added it into the answer